# How do I find the appropriate app service for my website on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-graph

I have a website that is on Azure. I am trying to find the app service that corresponds to the url. Shockingly I can't just search the url on Azure to find it. So how do I determine which app service this website is on?

Please direct me using the UI, we don't have PowerShell set up on the Azure website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-portal) to do that.

> Open the Azure portal to find and use the Resource Graph Explorer following these steps to run your first Resource Graph query:
>
> 1. Select All services in the left pane. Search for and select Resource Graph Explorer.
> 2. In the Query 1 portion of the window, enter the query [..]

Please try the query below:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.web/sites"
| extend hostNameSslStates=parsejson(tostring(properties.hostNameSslStates))
| mv-expand hostNameSslStates
| project name, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, url = hostNameSslStates.name
| where url == "mywebapp.azurewebsites.net"
```

To get a complete list remove the `where` statement from the query.